# Having two ajax calls in one onclick with different div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having problem of to make the second ajax call work. Here is my code:

```
function putThis(control){
var getid = control.innerText;
var first = $("#from[name=from]").val();
var second = $("#to[name=to]").val();

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'testtable.php',
    data: {id: getid,from: first,to: second},
    cache: false,
    global: false,
    success:function(data)
    {
    $("#result").empty();
    $("#result").append(data);
    //alert("Success: " + getid + " " + first + " to " + second);
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'subtable.php',
    data:{uid: getid,start: first,end: second},
    cache: false,
    global: false,
    success : function(data)
    {
        $("#subtable").empty();
        $("#subtable").append(data);
    }
});
}
```

They have also different url and different div for return value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain what is your problem in more details?

Comment: I have 2 tables one was for attendance and the second is for total. I put every results in separate div but the first ajax call was the only one that is executed and not the second one.

Comment: 1) Check if there is any javascript exception while calling first ajax on browser console.

2) Check if you have any return attribute set on first ajax

Comment: I have return value for the first ajax call but no return value for the second one or should i set global to true?

Comment: can you share, how u r returning your value? if you r using "return" key word to return your value then control will never reach your second ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
$.when( 
   $.ajax({
    url: 'testtable.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {id: getid,from: first,to: second}
   }),

   $.ajax({
      url: 'subtable.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {uid: getid,start: first,end: second}
   })
 ).done(function( data1, data2) {
  // data1 and data2 are arguments resolved for the testtable.php and subtable.php' ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]

   $("#result").empty();
   $("#result").append(data1);

    $("#subtable").empty();
    $("#subtable").append(data2);
});
```

just explore this link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: why var data = a1[0] + a2[0];?

Comment: @NewbieN it's just an example. let me edit it for you to understand more :)

Comment: I find your answer far more relevant than my own. I only leave mine "undeleted" so that others may see alternatives.

Comment: sorry because I can't see how does your code will help me solve my problem but if you can explain it farther or revise it to the extent that it will somehow contribute to solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your second ajax call is relient on the first ajax call, then you have to either store the result of the second ajax call (if it happens to arrive first) in some variable (setting a "state" variable to determine if it arrived first or second, reacting accordingly) or push the second ajax call within the "done" of the parent ajax call.

The complexity of the page will determine your requirements. Most problems of this sort can be resolved by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982793/3720511) on this page.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do it because I just copied the code that I am using.